# Running JS function in Karate feature

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, karate

I am creating an UI automated test using Karate framework.
One of the AUT screens can be open only with double-click.
When I try something like 'mouse('somelocator').doubleClick()' nothing happens. Then I decided to use JS that looks like this:

```
var myElement = document.getElementsByTagName("somelocator");
var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent('dblclick', true, true);
myElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

It's working perfectly when I try it in Chrome JS console.
The problem is that when I try to use it in Karate feature file

```
* def myDblClick = 
    """
    function() { 
      var myElement = document.getElementsByTagName("somelocator");
      var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
      clickEvent.initEvent('dblclick', true, true);
      myElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    }
    """
  * myDblClick()
```

I receive

> failed features: js failed:
> 01: myDblClick()
>
> org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "document" is
> not defined

What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS that needs to be run in the browser has to be expressed as a string. This is explained in detail here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#karate-vs-the-browser

So I think this will work (haven't tried it):

```
* def myDblClick = 
"""
function(tagName) {     
  def rawJs = `
    var myElement = document.getElementsByTagName('${tagName}');
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent('dblclick', true, true);
    myElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);    
  `;
  var driver = karate.get('driver');
  driver.script(rawJs);
}
"""
* myDblClick('input')
```

You already mentioned that you tried double-click which is supposed to be possible via the `mouse()` API: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#mouse - would be good if you can provide some hints on whether this can be improved in Karate.