# Karate - Doubleclick on all header of an table in webpage

Tags: maven, karate

I was trying to let the code double click on header of table to expand its width but cannot make it.
The table itself can be expand width after double click manually.
I just want to double click all of the header in the table.

Example of table behavior

1.

[image]

2. after double click header 1

[image]

1. I've used doubleClick() - a function of Karate (ref.https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/karate-core/#click) but the script doesn't click anything.
2. I've tried to use dispatchEvent > dbclickEvent in .feature file

```
* script('var dbclickEvent = new MouseEvent('dblclick', {
bubble: true,
view: window
})')

* script('document.querySelectorAll(th).dispatchEvent(dbclickEvent)')
```

It gives error of dispatchEvent is not a function

Also tried

```
* script('document.querySelectorAll(th).ondbclick()')
```

and

```
* script('document.querySelectorAll(th).dbclick()')
```

gives the same error

> > TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).ondbclick is not a function

> > TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).dbclick is not a function

I was wondering if this error cause from jQuery or not ?
If it is please recommend me to install jQuery to my karate project , if not can recommend other workaround that would work please.

Comment: sorry this is hard to diagnose remotely. try using the `mouse()` API: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#mouse - also I think you are using `script()` wrong, so read this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#karate-vs-the-browser - and finally see this similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74237960/143475